# Android Studio Build menu commands not working

Tags: gradle, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio 0.4 on Ubuntu, gradle 1.9.

Those commands run from the command line are working fine:

```
cd /path/to/project/
./gradlew clean
./gradlew build
```

But after running anny command in Android Studio Build menu nothing happens. Project is not being built, no errors.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Anything in the Gradle console window? Anything interesting in `idea.log`? (Help menu > Show log)

Comment: @Scott Thanks for the tip. Looks like the problem is here: `ExternalSystemException: Supplied javaHome is not a valid folder. You supplied: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64:`. But from the console, `echo $JAVA_HOME` returns `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle` which is a valid path to my JDK installation (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The workaround for this problem is to delete Android Studio and gradle config files in user home directory. Then Android Studio asks for the JVM upon first start.

Answer (score 29):

You can go to File -> Project Structure and set the jdk path there.